# Topological Continuous Functions and Non-Open Sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let us consider a function $\ \mathbf F $ defined from $\ \mathbf X $ to $\ \mathbf Y $ , where $\ \mathbf X $ and $\ \mathbf Y $ are topological spaces. Now by definition , a continuous function is one for which the preimage of every open set in $\ \mathbf Y $ is an open set in $\ \mathbf X $.

However, I guess there can be functions which permit the assumption of more than one pre-image value.  Is it possible for a non-open set in $\ \mathbf Y $ to have a pre-image which is an open set in $\ \mathbf X $ ?

Comment: I had an error in my response before- I think I got that all sorted now. I've been studying a bit too much today, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Consider any set $X$ with $|X| \geq 2$. Then if $\mathcal{T}$ is the indiscrete topology on $X$ we have: $id_X: (X,\mathcal{P}(X)) \rightarrow (X,\mathcal{T})$ is continuous and the pre-image of every subset is open in $(X,\mathcal{P}(X))$.

I'm not sure what is meant by 'more than one pre-image value'? If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function, then for any subset $B$ of $Y$, the pre-image of $B$ under $f$ is uniquely determined by $f$. So it seems to me that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I meant , multiple valued inverse functions . For example , inverse of the sine function or cosine function . Simply , a set K1,which is open in Y having pre-image P ,which is open in X and at the same time a set K2,which is not open in Y having the same pre-image P. Is this scenario possible ?

Comment: he means $card(f^{-1}(\{x\})) >1$

Comment: Take $X=\{a,b,c\}$ endowed with the discrete topology and $Y=\{a,b,c,d\}$ with topology $\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b\}, Y\}$ and $f: X\rightarrow Y$ by $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=f(c)=b$. Then, $f$ is continuous and $f^{-1}[\{b\}]=\{b,c\}=f^{-1}[\{b,c,d\}]$ ($\{b,c,d\}$ is not open, although $\{b\}$ is.)

Answer (score 2):

Sure: let $\mathbf{Y}$ be any space where $y_0\in \mathbf{Y}$ is not open, and consider the constant function $f\colon x\mapsto y_0\colon \mathbf{X}\to\mathbf{Y}$; then $f^{-1}(\{y_0\}) = \mathbf{X}$.

Answer (score 1):

The following example has always been very enlightening to me as it shows how important the underlying topology is.

Consider $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology and $[0,1)$ with the subspace topology (induced by the inclusion) of $\mathbb R$. Have a look at

$$ i: [0,1) \to \mathbb R$$
the inclusion map. $[0,1) \subset \mathbb R$ is **not open** as $1$ is not an interior point, but $i^{-1}([0,1))=[0,1)$ is the whole set and therefore open in the subspace $[0,1)$.